# Rtools40: Where are make utilities (bash, make, etc)?

Tags: r, rtools, r-4.0.0

Hi i tried to upgrade my R installation and i am not able to finish it. I installed RTools40 from here
https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
and it clearly states:
"After installation is complete, you need to perform one more step to be able to compile R packages: you need to put the location of the Rtools make utilities (bash, make, etc) on the PATH."
I do not know the Path to these Utilites. How do i find these Rtools utilities?

EDIT:
Solved it. I had to insert the path of the folder which was in rtools40/usr/bin.

Comment: `list.files("c:/Rtools40", "find\\.exe", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: But in general, when looking for paths within an installation directory, when you see `.../bin/`, it indicates you might have other bin variants such as `.../usr/bin/`, which is where it is found on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @r2evans(Aug 11 '20 at 17:00) is super helpful:

`list.files("c:/Rtools40", "find\\.exe", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`

Then, just add:

`writeLines('PATH="YOUR PATH"', con = "~/.Renviron")`,

and the problem will be solved.